# Apex callout fails suddenly

Tags: apex, integration, callout, soap, wsdl2apex

I am making an apex  SOAP callout to an external system. THe connection worked fine last week but suddenly it is failing now due and it gives me this 
error:

```
Apex callout Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':h4'
```

When I tested the webservice throught SOAP UI it works fine and gives me the response. The external system and I are wondering what change has happended and why
this error has popped out from no where. Any insights of what I should check when this error comes up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the debug log for the raw CALLOUT_RESPONSE. You might need to do this in a developer edition org to see it.

An `h4` in the response suggests you are getting an HTML page back in the response. This usually happens if the server (or proxy) is trying to redirect you to a login or error page.

I've seen cases where the API server rejects certain IP address, which could explain why it works with SOAP UI from your machine but not from Salesforce servers.

Comment: This error came up suddenly. Does it mean the end system might have modified schema or anything? I get response as NULL. THe external system say they have not made any change

Comment: The clue will be in the response that contains the h4 rather than a SOAP envelope. If you can't get the CALLOUT_RESPONSE look for the CALLOUT_REQUEST that contains the SOAP body and then replay that using SOAP UI.

Comment: I confirmed that there are no IP restriction.

Comment: I see the CALLOUT_REQUEST which is in a different format since I am calling it through wsdl2apex class. For using it with SOAP UI i would need a xml format correct? And Response I am just get as NULL

Comment: If you are making the callout from a Sandbox or production org then you won't see the raw SOAP request. Just a dump of the Apex object before it gets converted. You can convert that (by hand) to the SOAP XML request.

Comment: What do you mean you are getting null for the response? That doesn't line up with the error message listed in the question.

Comment: Sorry Daniel. The error was because I was using the wrong username ... it was case sensitive and used a wrong case in username. Thus I was getting <H4> access denied </H4> in response